# paypal payment action missing

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I did what necessarily the latest available documentation says in integrating the PayPal in our shop system. I just found out that it seems like there PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION parameter in NVP.

I get payment details using the token and PayerID returned by SetExpressCheckout. When I output my returned cURL, I just found out this:

```
[CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
```

What seems to be the problem?

I use this query in cURL:

```
// Prepare PayPal API URL
$url = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";

// $PAYMENTACTION = "Sale"

// Prepare PayPal NVP (Name-Value Pair) payment request
$nvp = "METHOD=" . $SETMETHOD;
$nvp .= "&VERSION=" . $VERSION;
$nvp .= "&USER=" . $USERNAME;
$nvp .= "&PWD=" . $PASSWORD;
$nvp .= "&SIGNATURE=" . $SIGNATURE;
$nvp .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $PAYMENTACTION;
$nvp .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $CURRENCY;
$nvp .= "&SOLUTIONTYPE=" . $SOLUTIONTYPE;
$nvp .= "&RETURNURL=" . $RETURNURL;
$nvp .= "&CANCELURL=" . $CANCELURL;
$nvp .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=" . $PAYMENTNAME0;
$nvp .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=" . $PAYMENTDESC0;
$nvp .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=" . $PAYMENTAMT0;
$nvp .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=" . $PAYMENTQTY0;
$nvp .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=" . $PAYMENTITEMAMT;
$nvp .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $PAYMENTAMT;
$nvp .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $CURRENCY;
$nvp .= "&LOCALECODE=" . $LOCALECODE;
$nvp .= "&HDRIMG=" . $HEADERLOGO;
$nvp .= "&PAYFLOWCOLOR=" . 262626;
```

Comment: I've never worked with the paypal system before, but a quick search says that paypal doesn't allow numbers with more than 2 decimals, and that that might be causing the problem?

Comment: @Nick - I think this doesn't concern that. Amount works fine, it's just that certain parameter **&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION** seems to be the issue.

Comment: Maybe you could try this as a workaround in case nobody knows the answer:
"The only workaround that I found was to do the GetExpressCheckoutDetails and check the CHECKOUTSTATUS variable to see if it is PaymentActionComplete. If so, I process the payment. If it is PaymentActionNotInitiated, I will do a DoExpressCheckoutPayment." -Although I really hope you find a better solution.

Answer (score 9):

`PaymentActionNotInitiated` does not refer to `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION`.
It merely means that you have not yet direct a buyer to the PayPal page in order to confirm his/her payment.

To recap, this is how Express Checkout works:

1. SetExpressCheckout sets up the payment and returns a token
2. You redirect the buyer to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN-HERE, where TOKEN-HERE is the token you received earlier
3. After the buyer has agreed to the payment, he is returned back to your site
4. You can call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and supply the token as a parameter to get the PAYERID of the buyer.
5. Call DoExpressCheckoutPayment with the token and PAYERID supplied to finalize the payment

Comment: i found in your profile this comment `play with PayPal API's for a living`. How is it possible?. Did Paypal pay for your work in stackoverflow??

Comment: (A little offtopic, but I work for PayPal Merchant Technical Services.)